# Adjust google spreadsheet row by one

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My current spreadsheet has 1 frozen row as the header. I am trying to figure out how to adjust, slice, move, etc by 1. So far I am able to output

```
[17-05-23 22:00:38:744 EDT] A6
[17-05-23 22:00:38:744 EDT] A5
[17-05-23 22:00:38:745 EDT] A4
[17-05-23 22:00:38:745 EDT] A3
[17-05-23 22:00:38:746 EDT] A2
[17-05-23 22:00:38:746 EDT] A1
```

Row A1 is the header and needs to be skipped.

Here is what I have for the code.

```
function steamData() 
{
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  //values[i][y] y is index of the column starting from 0
  //values[y][i] y is index of the row starting from 0
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var vLength = values.length.toString().slice(0);
  for( i = sheet.getLastRow(); i > 0; i--) 
  {
    Logger.log("A"+ i);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I feel completely dumb now. I just did a continue on the loop iteration....

```
if (i === 1) { continue; }
```